# How can I use REGEX to format 'phone numbers?

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have two 'phone numbers listed in different formats, but want just to extract the digits only:

```
17347545296

(734) 754-5296
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use `REGEXREPLACE` and remove all non numeric characters:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[^0-9]+", "")
```

If a given cell could also have digits not belonging to the actual phone number, then we would have to do more work.  But the above suggestion should work for your sample data shown.

Answer (score 1):

Also using [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245) but avoids errors where "A1" is Number format and a simpler expression:

```
=regexreplace(A1&"","\D","")
```